# Laravel artisan down with message parameter with spaces gives Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-artisan

I run the artisan:

```
php artisan down --message "Going down for maintenance" --retry=60
```

[UPDATE] OR run it like @Remul suggested:

```
php artisan down --message="Going down for maintenance" --retry=60
```

then both gives me the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
 Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".
```

If run command with no spaces like this:

```
php artisan down --message "Going_down_for_maintenance" --retry=60
```

No error occurs

Comment: Can you try with the equal sign for the message parameter: `php artisan down --message="Going down for maintenance" --retry=60`.

Comment: I agree with Remul. Without the equal sign, it will think that "Going down for maintenance" is another argument. If you look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/configuration#maintenance-mode), it shows `php artisan down --message="Upgrading Database" --retry=60 `

Comment: did not work gives the same error

Comment: @aynber I notice that symfony code has this: `public function __construct(array $argv = null, InputDefinition $definition = null)
    {
        if (null === $argv) {
            $argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
        }
` and the problem lies in that global, so in php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using php 7.0.14

I figured out:

Problem is actually how php is getting arguments from command line
In vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php I could understand that php gets argfuments like this:

```
0 => "artisan"
  1 => "down"
  2 => "--message=Going"
  3 => "down"
  4 => "for"
  5 => "maintenance"
  6 => "--retry=60"
```

So to even make sure I made a script of my own with this content:

```
<?php

var_dump($argv);
```

And I run it:

```
php -v;php test_argv.php "parm with space" other_parameter
```

The output was:

```
PHP 7.0.14 (cli) (built: Jan 30 2017 15:45:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "test_argv.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "parm"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "with"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "space"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "other_parameter"
}
```

I run it in other machine with a different version of PHP and look at my results:

```
PHP 7.1.5 (cli) (built: Sep 19 2017 10:48:01) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(13) "test_argv.php"
  [1] =>
  string(15) "parm with space"
  [2] =>
  string(15) "other_parameter"
}
```

Looks like in php 7.0 and 7.1 argv parsing is quite different, one ignores the double quotes as string delimiter and the later don't

Comment: For future visitors, this answer is incorrect. Parsing arguments is the job of the shell, not PHP. And it's very unlikely that any shell would "ignore" quotes in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

This is an unrelated problem, but this was the place where Google sent me as I made this mistake... soo..

The other common reason to get:

```
Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".
```

Is that you are providing an argument, when the artisan script is expecting an option. So you need to change

```
./artisan yourcommand:yoursubcommand some_kind_of_input
```

to

```
./artisan yourcommand:yoursubcommand --an_option=some_kind_of_input
```

The error just generally means that artisan was not expecting an additional argument of any kind to this command...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, just need to escape the message using backslashes:

```sh
php artisan down --message "Going\ down\ for\ maintenance" --retry=60
```

Answer (score -1):

This message is available in a JSON formatted file named storage/framework/down generated by  php artisan down command.

You can open that file and modify it.

Goodluck