# Too many arguments, expected arguments "command". laravel graphql passport

Tags: laravel, graphql

I've got a problem when I write the command :

`php artisan passport:client –password password`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191654/laravel-artisan-down-with-message-parameter-with-spaces-gives-too-many-arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel artisan down with message parameter with spaces gives Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191654/laravel-artisan-down-with-message-parameter-with-spaces-gives-too-many-arguments)

Comment: Please add some context to your question like "What are you trying to achieve by this command?"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `password` part. The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client) tell you to just run:

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

The `--password` keyword is to specify the type of client, not to specify a password.

If you run `php artisan passport:client --help` you'll see descriptions of the different client types:

```
Description:
  Create a client for issuing access tokens

Usage:
  passport:client [options]

Options:
      --personal                     Create a personal access token client
      --password                     Create a password grant client
      --client                       Create a client credentials grant client
```